# How to get intermediate output grad in Pytorch model

Tags: pytorch

we can get loss of last layer by `loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y_true)`, and results in a `loss: Tensor`

then we call `loss.backward()` to do back propagation.

after `optimizer.step()` we could see updated `model.parameters()`

taking below example

```py
y = Model1(x) # with optimizer1
z = Model2(y) # with optimizer2
loss = loss_fn(z, z_true)
loss.backward()
optimizer2.optimize() # update Model2 parameters

# in order to update Model1 parameters I think we should do
y.backward(grad_tensor=the_output_gradient_from_Model2)
optimizer1.optimize()
```

How to get the intermediate back propagation result? e.g. the gradient of output **grad**, which will be taken by y_pred.backward(grad_tensor=**grad**).

Update: The solution is setting `required_grad=True` and take Tensor `x.grad`. Thanks for the answers.

PS: The scenario is I am doing a federated learning, the model is split into 2 parts. The first part takes input and forward to second part. And it need the second part to calculate the loss and back propagate the loss to first part, so that the first part takes the loss and do its own back propagation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume you're referring to intermediate gradients when you say *"loss of a specific layer"*.

You can access the gradient of the layer with respect to the output loss by accessing the [`grad`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.grad.html) attribute on the parameters of your model which require gradient computation.

Here is a simplistic setup:

```
>>> f = nn.Sequential(
       nn.Linear(10,5), 
       nn.Linear(5,2), 
       nn.Linear(2, 2, bias=False), 
       nn.Sigmoid())

>>> x = torch.rand(3, 10).requires_grad_(True)
>>> f(x).mean().backward()
```

Navigate through all the parameters per layer:

```
>>> for n, c in f.named_children():
...    for p in c.parameters():
...       print(f'<{n}>:{p.grad}')

<0>:tensor([[-0.0054, -0.0034, -0.0028, -0.0058, -0.0073, -0.0066, -0.0037, -0.0044, 
             -0.0035, -0.0051],
            [ 0.0037,  0.0023,  0.0019,  0.0040,  0.0050,  0.0045,  0.0025,  0.0030,
              0.0024,  0.0035],
            [-0.0016, -0.0010, -0.0008, -0.0017, -0.0022, -0.0020, -0.0011, -0.0013,
             -0.0010, -0.0015],
            [ 0.0095,  0.0060,  0.0049,  0.0102,  0.0129,  0.0116,  0.0066,  0.0077,
              0.0063,  0.0091],
            [ 0.0005,  0.0003,  0.0002,  0.0005,  0.0006,  0.0006,  0.0003,  0.0004,
              0.0003,  0.0004]])
<0>:tensor([-0.0090,  0.0062, -0.0027,  0.0160,  0.0008])
<1>:tensor([[-0.0035,  0.0035, -0.0026, -0.0106, -0.0002],
            [-0.0020,  0.0020, -0.0015, -0.0061, -0.0001]])
<1>:tensor([-0.0289, -0.0166])
<2>:tensor([[0.0355, 0.0420],
            [0.0354, 0.0418]])
```

Comment: This seems help from my instinct. If I am right, the first `<0>,<1>,<2>` are weight gradients, which will used by optimizer. How about the second `<0>,<1>` are they the cross-layer value calculated by the chain rule with the final loss? And seems they are the tensors I want to back propagate according to my description(the tensor needed should be a cross-layer value).

Comment: No, I am looping through all the parameter gradients for each layer `<0>`, `<1>`, and `<2>`, the first one refers to the `nn.Linear`'s weight gradient while the second (if any) refers to its bias gradient. What do you mean by *"cross-layer value"* exactly?

Comment: Let me explain the scenario. Taking your example, assume first two layers `nn.Linear(10,5), nn.Linear(5,2)` are the 1st part model in my case and the rest `nn.Linear(2, 2, bias=False), nn.Sigmoid())` are the 2nd part. The 2nd part back propagates and should get a [2, 2] gradient matrix if I am not wrong. And I want to send a `Tensor` to 1st model which could call `backward()` to do the rest of thing. What should this `Tensor` be? And please correct me if anything wrong

Comment: I have edited the question. And sorry for the previous mistaken description.

Comment: I did some search and I think the solution should be setting `required_grad=true` and `x.grad`?

Comment: Yes indeed, that's the way if you want to have the gradient of the loss with respect to the input.

Answer (score 0):

To supplement gradient related answer(s), it should to say that you can't get the **loss** of the layer, loss is model level concept, generally, you can't say, which layer is responsible for error. See, if model deep enough one can freeze any model layer, and it can still train to high accuracy.